# Access violation when writing to vector at runtime

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm pretty new to C++ and just getting started with pointers and such. I'm making a simple game with SFML. I've made a vector "drawList" to store all the shapes in the game that will be rendered on screen. If I add the shapes to the vector before the main loop starts it works fine, however when I add objects at runtime I get an Access violation error on the following code:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < drawList.size(); i++){
        window.draw(*drawList[i]);
    }
```

I think that the *drawlist[i] is an invalid pointer, however attempts to fix the issue so far have been unsuccessfull. The drawList vector and the method to add objects to it are setup like this in a header:

```
extern std::vector<const sf::Drawable*> drawList;

struct Globals {
    void AddDrawable(const sf::Drawable &drawable);
};
```

and like this in the associated cpp:

```
std::vector<const sf::Drawable*> drawList;
void Globals::AddDrawable(const sf::Drawable & drawable){
    drawList.push_back(&drawable);
}
```

I then try to add a shape to the vector in the constructor of a newly instatiated projectile class by calling the "AddDrawable" method and giving it the following method as parameter:

```
    sf::RectangleShape& GetShape() { return shape; };
```

I feel like there is something really obvious going wrong with the references and pointers of things but so far I've not been able to figure it out. If anyone could suggest me ways to adress this issue it would be greatly appriciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I'll try to give some more context on Cris Luengo's suggestion, I have a main.cpp containing the main while loop. Before that while loop is initiated I instantiate a `Player` and a `Projectile` class. Inside the while loop I check if there is anything to update and draw in a forloop like so:

```
int main() {
Projectile bullet = Projectile(WINDOW_WIDTH /2.f, WINDOW_HEIGHT /2.f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
Player player = Player(WINDOW_WIDTH / 2.f, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 1.2f);

while (true) {
    window.clear(Color::Black);
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::Escape)) break;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < updateList.size(); i++){
        updateList[i]();
        window.draw(*drawList.at(i));
    }
    window.display();
```

The `updateList` and `drawList` are both vectors that get filled from the constructors of the `Player` and the `Projectile` classes like so (This is identical for both the player and the projectile constructor respectively):

```
Projectile::Projectile(float mX, float mY, float velX, float velY){
    velocity = sf::Vector2f(velX, velY);
    GetShape().setPosition(mX, mY);
    //other shape stuff
    Globals globals;
    updateIndex = globals.AddToUpdateList([this]() {Update(); });
    globals.AddDrawable(GetShape());
}
```

As shown earlier, the `GetShape()` method is setup in the `Player` and `Projectile` headers like like this:

```
sf::RectangleShape& GetShape() { return shape; };
```

As it stands right now, this code works when I instantiate the objects to be added to the `drawList` before the while loop starts. If I read new data to it at runtime, when it is also being read, the program throws an access violation error in the forloop when the `drawList` is being accessed.

I use the same code when adding things to the `drawList` at runtime. I simply instantiate a new `Projectile` on a button press. The idea is that the constructor of the instantiated class adds the needed data to the lists (The `updateList` works fine)
Thank you in advance

Comment: And who holds the ownership of `shape` instances returned by `GetShape`? You should probably get rid of all those `Globals` and `extern` things.

Comment: The problem is lifetime of objects that you add via `Globals::AddDrawable`, when they are created, and when destroyed?

Comment: perhaps a read of [C++ lifetime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) would be helpful

Comment: btw, you don't have to add to all your c++ questions that you are learning the language :) it just becomes redundant.

Comment: @VTT `shape` instances are owned by the classes such as `Player` or `Projectile`. They are defined in the constructors of said classes. The public `GetShape` methods only return the shape of the object.

Comment: @fghj I have considered the possibility, but I dont yet destroy or remove anything. It purely goes wrong when I add a new object at runtime. I've read about some things like memory being reallocated when it is written to, making the pointers invalid, but as of right now I'm not sure if thats what happening here. Thanks for the link though, I'll read into it

Comment: You need to show us how you create the objects and store their pointers in this global thing. This is one of those cases where a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: @CrisLuengo i have added some more code. I hope this gives you a better idea of what happens and how :)

Comment: Please make a [mcve] or at least show the code where you add the new shapes to your vectors.

Comment: There is still no way of understanding what is going on in your code. There is a reason we ask for a MCVE. Please read the text both I and @super linked on how to create a MCVE. Yes it takes time to make one. But without it it's unlikely we'll ever be able understand your issue. I often find my own bug when I'm creating a MCVE. It really helps you hone in on where the problem lies.